# HTML/CSS buttons work but don't show any effect unless page is refreshed

Tags: html, css, button, refresh, slideshow

This is the first time I'm asking around here. Hopefully you guys can help me.

For a client I'm creating a website for a bar/restaurant. A part of the page setup for the menu card. I created 3 buttons underneath to switch between diner, lunch and drinks. Whenever I hit one of the buttons I see the link change. The weird part; I can't figure out why the image doesn't change. If I refresh the page (the changed links let's say) it shows the image it's supposed to show.

I guess my question is. How can I make sure that the image changes with the button press without having to reload the page.

**HTML**

```
    <span id="menu1"></span>
    <span id="menu2"></span>
    <span id="menu3"></span>

    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="img/menu1.jpg" class="slider-image">
        <img src="img/menu2.jpg" class="slider-image">
        <img src="img/menu3.jpg" class="slider-image">
    </div>

    <div class="button-container">
      <a href="#menu1" class="slider-button"></a>
      <a href="#menu2" class="slider-button"></a>
      <a href="#menu3" class="slider-button"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide-container {
  width: 495px;
  height: 750px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.image-container {
  width: 1485px;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;

}

.slider-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 495px;
}

.button-container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: black;
}

#menu1:target ~ .image-container {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#menu2:target ~ .image-container {
  left: -495px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#menu3:target ~ .image-container {
  left: -990px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

If anyone has any idea and could help. I thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by image change? page should scroll to that point...right?

Comment: I now understand what you're saying. Yes it should scroll to the right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See following code snippet, you need add `id` to an element and specify that `id` in anchor tag so that browser will scroll page up to that content on clicking the anchor.

```css
#section1,
#section2,
#section3,
#section4 {
  height: 400px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
<a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
<a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
<a href="#section4">Section 4</a>
<div id="container">
  <div id="section1">SECTION 1</div>
  <div id="section2">SECTION 2</div>
  <div id="section3">SECTION 3</div>
  <div id="section4">SECTION 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the end I made it work with ID's thanks for the idea;)